# 404 error on every post and page other than home

Tags: posts, pages, 404-error, homepage

I am developing a wordpress theme and I think at some point I messed something up pretty badly in the wordpress system because nothing works anymore.

I have tried several different themes, mine and the ones that come with wordpress.  I have removed all plugins.  I even reinstalled all of the wordpress files through ftp.  No matter what I try I always get 404 errors when I try to view a page or a post or anything other than the actual home page.  I have not anything fancy with the urls.  For example, I am trying to view the default "Hello World!" post simply using the /1.  I haven't added an .htaccess file.  All of the back end stuff is working fine.  I don't know how this makes sense, and I don't know where to go next while trying to debug this.

Comment: Without mod_rewrite the URL for the first post is `/?p=1`, not `/1`.

Comment: Weird, I was just clicking the view button on the post.  Why would it get it wrong?

Comment: Maybe you have tried to enable pretty permalinks, but the `.htaccess` could not be written or mod_rewrite is not enabled.

Comment: I tried to freshly reinstall wordpress because things like that were messed up.  I am not sure I got rid of all of the settings I am trying again also deleting the database.

Comment: Settings > Permalink > (without any change) click "Save Changes" to refresh the permalink structure. - may be the problem is far beyond this, but trial and error is everything of debugging to me. :)